# A good intro to information theory, please?

Tags: information-theory

I know about [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_entropy) and MacKay's [Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms](http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/itprnn/book.html) (is it appropriate as textbook?). A textbook starting with Shannon's entropy and going through Conditional entropy and Mutual information is sought... Any idea? If you  are following such a course at your university, which textbook is used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following textbook during my studies in CS at [EPFL](http://www.epfl.ch). IMO, it's well written, with good explainations, and covers more than enough for an introduction to the domain.

[Elements of Information Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471241954)

[image: Elements of Information Theory]

EDIT: For further reading, here are some other readings that my professor did recommend. I did not read them (shame on me), so I can't say if they're good or not.

1. R. G. Gallager, [Information Theory and Reliable Communication](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471290483), Wiley, 1968.
2. D. MacKay, [Information Theory, Inference & Learning Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521642981), Cambridge University Press, 2008. (you already mentioned it)
3. I. Csiszar and J. Korner, [Information Theory: Coding Theorems for Discrete Memoryless Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9630574403), Akademiai Kiado, 1997.
4. [C. E. Shannon, The Mathematical Theory of Communication](http://lcmwww.epfl.ch/lib/exe/fetch.php?id=en%3Acourses%3A2009-2010%3Aitc%3Arecommended_reading&cache=cache&media=en:courses:2007-2008:itc:shannon1948.pdf)

Comment: Yup, pretty much the way to go. For an introductory treatment, stick to chapter 2.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If the question would be on "advanced treatment of Information Theory", which is you answer?

Comment: Added some other recommended readings from my professor.

Comment: Chapter 2 of Cover/Thomas is large enough, and a complete understanding of that chapter is *necessary* (or equivalent material from another book, of course). But if you must go further, I'd say chapters 4, 5, and 7; then 8 and 9; then 10.